# Disable button even after refresh of page/component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, button

I have a button in my lightning component (aura), which will send out a notification to certain user.
In helper and controler there are events for success and failed. In case of success, I want to disable this button and keep it disabled even after component resp. site refresh.

I used `disabled="false"` (having a `aura:id="notifyButton"`) in markup and set it in success event in helper/controller via `let button = cmp.find('notifyButton');` and `button.set('v.disabled', true);`. Of course this will only set it for the respective component session, as it will be reset to the markup standard setting.

Is there a best practice way to keep buttons disabled? I was thinking about using some kind of helper checkbox field in the object I am reference-using for this component, but this is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me I made it work now as already mentioned via a checkbox boolean flag on a related object.
This checkbox value will be queried in an apex controller and transfered to the component via the .js helper.
Depending on the boolean value, the button will be shown on init render or not.
If it is shown, it can be clicked. On click, via .js helper the value for the checkbox will be set accordingly in the apex controller.